# How to calculate cost matrix for cost sensitive meta classifier?

Tags: classification

I have an imbalanced data set with 12 classes and want to use cost sensitive ensemble for classification,  but I don't know how to calculate cost matrix for the classes.

My question: what costs should I insert in cost matrix and how to calculate it for cost sensitive meta classifier in WEKA?

Comment: You don't 'compute' costs. Either misclassifications *have* different relative costs in your intended application or they don't.

Answer (score 2):

Learning costs of classification is not straight forward. It can either come from domain experts or based on your problem. You cannot just put arbitrary values in the cost matrix to get some answer because you need to have proper interpretation of the elements of the cost matrix